# Hide and then append data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

By Clicking a link `.link`, I want to append a data data in a div `.list`. I want to set it initially hidden and then show it (to create a fading effect). I am trying following but it does not seem to do anything (neither I get any error). What's wrong with it?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="list">

        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="link">click me</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    var wrap = $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.list' );
    var mydata = "test data";

    $(mydata).hide(1000, function(){                        
        $(wrap).append($(mydata));
        $(mydata).show(6000);
    });

});
```

**JSFiddle Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/9z06nvh7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mydata` is a text, so when it is passed to jQuery it will be considered as a selector thus no element will be returned and the hide call will not do anything after that.

You need to hide the `wrap` element and show it

```js
$('.link').click(function(e) {
  var wrap = $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.list');
  var mydata = "test data";
  wrap.hide().html(mydata).show(6000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="list"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="link">click me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `wrap` instead `mydata` for `hide` and `show`

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    var wrap = $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.list' );
    var mydata = "test data";

    $(wrap).hide(1000, function(){                        
        $(wrap).append($(mydata));
        $(wrap).show(6000);
    });

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/muhammadusmaann/9z06nvh7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You are hiding and showing `mydata` instead of `wrap` which is a list div, see below code

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    var wrap = $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.list' );
    var mydata = "test data";

    $(wrap).hide(1000, function(){                      
        $(wrap).append(mydata);
        $(wrap).show(6000);
    });

});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9z06nvh7/1/)**